# Class _NSZombie_GraphicPath is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm getting the following run time output:

"Class _NSZombie_GraphicPath is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined."

Have no clue how to fix this. There are a couple of other questions that cover this, but it seems in those unit testing was involved. Has anyone ever come across this problem before and if so how was it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

It implies that two images and/or static libraries export the class GraphicPath. For example, one may be your app, and the other a unit test. A library you link to could also export that class. In any event, you should review your projects' compilations phases *including all dependencies*, and ensure that GraphicPath.m is compiled exactly once, then remove all others. Also note that it is possible to compile the file twice for the same target. I expect that you would also see a log warning  when running with zombies disabled. You can also use `nm` to dump an image's symbol names.

Comment: note that by image the submitter is referring to the results of compilation of your project and not to pictures.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I did check the build phases in the project settings, and I only saw one listing of GraphicPath, and I don't have any dependencies. I ran with zombies disables, and did not get a log warning. Do you know anything else I could try?

Comment: @CoDEFRo sure -- but they're stretches. perhaps they will help you identify the problem. other possibilities: a) you have accidentally included GraphicPath.m someplace b) `@implementation GraphicPath` is declared in a header c) you forgot to name a category upon GraphicPath d) you have synthesized a class at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for that Justin going to take a look at those.

Comment: Hey Justin, one quick question. I noticed for some weird reason there had been two copies of my app on my phone. Do you think this could have possibly done it? If they were open or running at the same time somehow?

Comment: @CoDEFRo no. the apps would be loaded into separate address spaces. the objc runtime data of other processes should not be accessible to your app's process. it would be a big security risk, if that were the case. there would also be a ton of such collisions -- which would be very capable of causing undefined behavior, crashes, etc.

Comment: Hi Justin, i've got an even better one,  same structure as original posters,  but it is "NSZombie_CalAgentLinkUserNotificationsOperation I'm sure I don't have something named that,  I don't have any unit tests, and I am pretty sure i don't have any third party libraries. I only have One target...  and the most interesting part,  I can run the app once, and not get this warning,  and without making any changes,  get the warning,   and or visa versa....  usually all i ahve to do is hit "run" again,  and it is gone until out of the blue it shows up again.

Comment: @hokkuk `+[NSBundle bundleForClass:]` is an API you may be able to use to locate the library which exports `CalAgentLinkUserNotificationsOperation`. of course, the library needs to be loaded at the time you call it. if `CalAgentLinkUserNotificationsOperation` is not your class, perhaps it is defined in a private framework. the NSZombie prefix of course means that the class being registered is an NSZombie variant (i.e. a class is zombified as this class when its ref count reaches zero). the runtime just creates these variants when zombies are enabled.